# Creating Spark RDD or Dataframe from an External Source

Tags: apache-spark

I am building a substantial application in Java that uses Spark and Json. I anticipate that the application will process large tables, and I want to use Spark SQL to execute queries against those tables. I am trying to use a streaming architecture so that data flows directly from an external source into Spark RDDs and dataframes. I'm having two difficulties in building my application.

First, I want to use either JavaSparkContext or SparkSession to parallelize the data. Both have a method that accepts a Java List as input. But, for streaming, I don't want to create a list in memory. I'd rather supply either a Java Stream or an Iterator. I figured out how to wrap those two objects so that they look like a List, but it cannot compute the size of the list until after the data has been read. Sometimes this works, but sometimes Spark calls the size method before the entire input data has been read, which causes an unsupported operation exception.

Is there a way to create an RDD or a dataframe directly from a Java Stream or Iterator?

For my second issue, Spark can create a dataframe directly from JSON, which would be my preferred method. But, the DataFrameReader class has methods for this operation that require a string to specify a path. The nature of the path is not documented, but I assume that it represents a path in the file system or possibly a URL or URI (the documentation doesn't say how Spark resolves the path). For testing, I'd prefer to supply the JSON as a string, and in the production, I'd like the user to specify where the data resides. As a result of this limitation, I'm having to roll my own JSON deserialization, and it's not working because of issues related to parallelization of Spark tasks.

Can Spark read JSON from an InputStream or some similar object?

These two issues seem to really limit the adaptability of Spark. I sometimes feel that I'm trying to fill an oil tanker with a garden hose.

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: If built in datasources are not fit for your requirements .. You can always implement custom datasource which can handle your use case ..

Comment: Please add details.

Comment: check this for how to create spark datasource v2 & may be it will help you to write your own logic ... link - http://shzhangji.com/blog/2018/12/08/spark-datasource-api-v2/ ..

Comment: Thanks. This looks potentially useful, but it is complex and I will need to think about it. I wonder why, with all my searching, I never came across this before?

Comment: what i am telling is you can write custom logic using data source api v2 if existing data sources are not supporting

Comment: I looked at the presentation you pointed to and also found an example at https://github.com/spirom/spark-data-sources. But I don't see how the data source api v2 helps. Two issues: 
1) I don't see how SparkSession loads the correct DataSourceReader. Apparently, this is specified by the format method, which takes a string argument. Looks like a class name, but if so it's a weird kind of call.
2) The DataSourceReader's other arguments -- options, etc. -- take only path strings as parameters. I need to supply a string of JSON. I don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion. After a lot of work, I was able to adapt the example at github.com/spirom/spark-data-sources. It is not straightforward, and because the DataSourceV2 API is still evolving, my solution may break in a future iteration. The details are too intricate to post here, so if you are interested, please contact me directly.